# Insert XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Good afternoon all.

Currently, I have make a small demo with XML in SQl Server.

I have table with name: `tb_xml_demo(ID, Name, Descr)`

And each time when I insert to this table. ID column like this:

```
001, 002, 003 ....
```

This is my procedure

```
alter proc sp_xml_demo_cud
@p_xml xml
as
begin
    declare @dochandle int;

    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @dochandle output,@p_xml;

    insert into tb_xml_demo(id, name, descr)
        select  
            (select 
                 format(isnull(convert(int, max(id)), 0) + 1, '000') 
             from tb_xml_demo) id,
            name,
            descr
        from 
            OPENXML(@dochandle,'/root/item',2)
        with
            (name nvarchar(50),
             descr nvarchar(50),
             crud varchar(1)
            )
    end;
```

And this is my xml:

```
exec sp_xml_demo_cud
    '<root>
         <item>
            <name>9876543</name>
            <descr>1sdfsd</descr> 
         </item>
         <item>
            <name>333</name>
            <descr>333</descr> 
         </item>
     </root>';
```

And this is result after executing the procedure:

```
    id  Name     Descr  
    001 9876543  1sdfsd
    001 333      333
```

Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Help you with what? There's no question here!

Comment: The question is not clear at all - but I think his problem is that both his IDs are coming out "001". This is because of the convert(int, max(id)) + 1 bit... of course that will assign the same ID for every row in the batch, and even if you insert rows individually it's a truly terrible way of doing things. Just use an identity int and let the server generate your IDs!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing this:

- create your table with a `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to let SQL Server handle the generation of unique ID values
- add a *computed* column (I called it `PaddedID`) that uses the system-generated, valid `ID` to display with leading zeroes
- parse the XML with the built-in, native XQuery functionality (instead of the legacy `OPENXML` stuff which is notorious for memory leaks)

This gives me this code:

```
-- create your table
CREATE TABLE tb_xml_demo
       (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        PaddedID AS RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED,
        Name VARCHAR(50), 
        Descr VARCHAR(100)
       )

-- declare your INPUT XML document
DECLARE @input XML = '<root>
         <item>
            <name>9876543</name>
            <descr>1sdfsd</descr> 
         </item>
         <item>
            <name>333</name>
            <descr>333</descr> 
         </item>
     </root>'

-- parse the XML using XQuery and insert the results into that newly created table
INSERT INTO dbo.tb_xml_demo
        (Name, Descr)
    SELECT
        ItemName = xc.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        ItemDescr = xc.value('(descr)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
    FROM
        @input.nodes('/root/item') AS XT(XC)

-- select the values from the table    
SELECT * FROM dbo.tb_xml_demo
```

and this results in an output of:

[image]

Comment: In different case, If ID column has complex structure like below :

         --Date: 2016/03/26
        DO201603260001
        DO201603260002
        DO201603260003
        DO201603260004 
How can I generate this column data when I use insert command from XML.

Please help me again.

Thank you so much.